# Does jflap support (+) operator in a regular expression?

Tags: finite-automata, dfa, jflap

Regular Expression is 01(0+1)<sup>*</sup>|0<sup>+</sup>

I want to convert this into a minimized DFA. JFlap does not seem to support the given regular expression,how do I verify for expression's having Kleene's closure?

If it accepts such expression's is there a special syntax to input them?